# Extract words that occur after a specific word

Tags: bash, unix, awk, grep

I'm fairly new to linux and need to extract all the words that occur after the word 'thy' from [this text.](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1120/pg1120.txt)

I have tried doing this using the following command:

```
 awk '{for(i=0;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="thy") print $(i+1)}' pg1120.txt
```

But the resulting output seems to be wrong. For example, there are 3 occurrences of the word 'master' after 'thy', but my code only detects two occurrences. How do I fix this?

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample to your question.

Comment: There are two occurrences of 'master' after 'thy'. And one after 'Thy'. So your code appears to work. If you want to make it case insensitive, replace your condition with `tolower($i)=="thy"`

Comment: indeed, there are only 2 occurrences of `master`. The question should be elaborated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only see 2 matches of `master` because you're searching for lowercase `thy`.
You may want to use `tolower($i)`, i.e.:

```
awk '{for(i=0;i<=NF;i++) if (tolower($i)=="thy") print $(i+1)}' pg1120.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

You can use `grep` with a lookbehind:

```
grep -Poi '(?<=\bthy )\w+' yourFile.txt
```

## Explanation

- `-P` enables perl regexes, which allow lookbehinds.
- `-o` prints only the matched words, instead of complete lines.
- `-i` ignore  case  distinctions, such that `thy` and `Thy` will be recognized.
- `(?<=\bthy )` is a lookbehind and ensures, that `\bthy` occurs before the match, without including `\bthy` into the match.
- The `\b` matches a word boundary and prevents `somewordthy` to match – we only want the word `thy`.
- `\w+` matches any word (after the `thy`). Matched words will be printed.

## Results

For the file content

```
Thy first match. thy. No match. Athy no match. thy thy thy.
```

the command prints

```
first
thy
thy
```

because

```
         Sentence ends after thy.
             ==> mo match
                  ↓
Thy first match. thy. No match. Athy no match. thy thy thy.  
    ^^^^^                         ↑                ^^^ ^^^
                        "Athy" instead of "thy".
                            ==> mo match
```

Matches are underlined with `^^^^^`.

Comment: Alternative : `grep -Pwo 'thy\K \w+' pg1120.txt`

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou There is a slight difference for cases like `thy thy thy`.

Comment: It all depends where you want to go... This snippet catch all after `thy` , even if it is a second `thy`

Answer (score 0):

One way is to replace all space with `\n` and use `grep`:

```
$ cat pg1120.txt | tr -s \  '\n' | grep -i -x -A 1 thy
thy
leather
--
thy
rule?
...
```

This extracts matches where `thy` is the last word of the record. `thy` could be regexp'd better as now it matches partial matches as well (`worthy` etc.) - or the `-x`switch for `grep`, courtesy of Mr. @RobertSeaman, thank you sir.

Using awk to get the thy from the previous record as well. Store previous word to `p` and compare it to current. First test material:

```
$ cat > test
thy master
thy. Master
thy
master
```

Code:

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(p=="thy")print $i;p=tolower($i)}}' test
master
master
```

The punctuations should be removed from `p` as well, since `thy. != thy`: Add
`gsub(/[^[:alpha:]]$/,"",p)` to the end of the program:

```
master
Master
master
```

Comment: You should also pass `-x` to `grep` to ensure it contains only the word `thy` and not just part of it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` with a loop may not be the fastest way to do it.

This may be the shortest.

```
grep -oP 'thy \K[^ ]+' file
```